# Regarding the title at the top of the sidebar - CoreUI

Tags: core-ui

I use CoreUI react js for my admin panel development.So I want to change the name at the top of the sidebar.
You can see a picture of the sidebar below. I can remove the name at the top which is **COREUI REACT.JS**. But I don't know how to replace the title I want for this.

[image]
[image]

When I remove the code from the highlighted file in the picture above, the title at the top disappears.

**logo-negative.js**

```
export const logoNegative = ['608 134', `
  <title>coreui react pro logo</title>
  <g>
    <g style="fill:#80d0ff;">
      <path d="M362.0177,90.1512,353.25,69.4149a.2507.2507,0,0,0-.2559-.1914H343.01a.2263.2263,0,0,0-.2559.2559V90.0233a.5657.5657,0,0,1-.64.64h-1.2163a.5652.5652,0,0,1-.64-.64V46.5028a.5655.5655,0,0,1,.64-.64H353.442a9.9792,9.9792,0,0,1,7.7437,3.2324A12.2,12.2,0,0,1,364.13,57.64a12.4389,12.4389,0,0,1-2.24,7.584,9.37,9.37,0,0,1-6.08,3.7441c-.1709.086-.2139.1915-.128.3194l8.7041,20.6084.064.2558q0,.5127-.5757.5118h-1.1523A.703.703,0,0,1,362.0177,90.1512ZM342.754,48.3593v18.496a.2259.2259,0,0,0,.2559.2559h10.3037a7.6713,7.6713,0,0,0,6.0166-2.5918,9.8807,9.8807,0,0,0,2.3037-6.8164,10.2875,10.2875,0,0,0-2.272-6.9756,7.6033,7.6033,0,0,0-6.0483-2.624H343.01A.2263.2263,0,0,0,342.754,48.3593Z"/>
      <path d="M401.3263,48.1034H381.2945a.2262.2262,0,0,0-.2558.2559v18.496a.2259.2259,0,0,0,.2558.2559h13.8238a.5664.5664,0,0,1,.6406.64v.96a.5663.5663,0,0,1-.6406.6406H381.2945a.2263.2263,0,0,0-.2558.2559v18.56a.2258.2258,0,0,0,.2558.2558h20.0318a.5671.5671,0,0,1,.6406.6407v.96a.566.566,0,0,1-.6406.64H379.1827a.5653.5653,0,0,1-.64-.64V46.5028a.5656.5656,0,0,1,.64-.64h22.1436a.5664.5664,0,0,1,.6406.64v.96A.5663.5663,0,0,1,401.3263,48.1034Z"/>
      <path d="M439.047,90.1512l-2.4317-8.832a.2971.2971,0,0,0-.32-.1924H419.5274a.2957.2957,0,0,0-.32.1924l-2.3681,8.7676a.6577.6577,0,0,1-.7036.5762H414.919a.5385.5385,0,0,1-.5756-.7041l12.0317-43.584a.6436.6436,0,0,1,.7041-.5117h1.6a.6442.6442,0,0,1,.7041.5117l12.16,43.584.0644.1923q0,.5127-.64.5118h-1.2163A.6428.6428,0,0,1,439.047,90.1512ZM419.9435,78.9188a.3031.3031,0,0,0,.2236.0967h15.4883a.3048.3048,0,0,0,.2236-.0967c.0645-.0635.0742-.1162.0322-.1592l-7.872-28.9287c-.043-.0849-.086-.1279-.128-.1279s-.0859.043-.1279.1279L419.9112,78.76C419.8683,78.8026,419.879,78.8553,419.9435,78.9188Z"/>
      <path d="M456.6017,87.911a11.6372,11.6372,0,0,1-3.3277-8.7041V57.1913a11.4158,11.4158,0,0,1,3.36-8.5762,12.0941,12.0941,0,0,1,8.8-3.2637,12.2566,12.2566,0,0,1,8.8643,3.2315,11.3927,11.3927,0,0,1,3.36,8.6084v.64a.5663.5663,0,0,1-.6406.6407l-1.28.0634q-.6408,0-.64-.5761v-.8321a9.289,9.289,0,0,0-2.6558-6.9121,10.6734,10.6734,0,0,0-14.0161,0,9.2854,9.2854,0,0,0-2.6563,6.9121V79.3993a9.2808,9.2808,0,0,0,2.6563,6.9121,10.67,10.67,0,0,0,14.0161,0,9.2843,9.2843,0,0,0,2.6558-6.9121v-.7686q0-.5757.64-.5752l1.28.0635a.5667.5667,0,0,1,.6406.6406v.5118a11.4952,11.4952,0,0,1-3.36,8.64,13.6227,13.6227,0,0,1-17.6963,0Z"/>
      <path d="M514.4376,46.5028v.96a.5658.5658,0,0,1-.64.6406H503.046a.2263.2263,0,0,0-.2559.2559v41.664a.566.566,0,0,1-.6406.64h-1.2158a.5652.5652,0,0,1-.64-.64V48.3593a.2266.2266,0,0,0-.2558-.2559H489.8619a.5656.5656,0,0,1-.64-.6406v-.96a.5656.5656,0,0,1,.64-.64H513.798A.5658.5658,0,0,1,514.4376,46.5028Z"/>
      <path d="M522.0665,89.5116a2.8385,2.8385,0,0,1-.8-2.0488,2.9194,2.9194,0,0,1,.8-2.1114,2.7544,2.7544,0,0,1,2.08-.832,2.8465,2.8465,0,0,1,2.9438,2.9434,2.7541,2.7541,0,0,1-.832,2.08,2.9221,2.9221,0,0,1-2.1118.8008A2.754,2.754,0,0,1,522.0665,89.5116Z"/>
      <path d="M542.4054,88.0077a11.3123,11.3123,0,0,1-3.2-8.416v-5.44a.5656.5656,0,0,1,.64-.64h1.2158a.5661.5661,0,0,1,.64.64v5.5039a9.1424,9.1424,0,0,0,2.5283,6.72,8.9745,8.9745,0,0,0,6.6875,2.5605,8.7908,8.7908,0,0,0,9.28-9.28V46.5028a.5655.5655,0,0,1,.64-.64h1.2163a.566.566,0,0,1,.64.64V79.5917a11.2545,11.2545,0,0,1-3.2325,8.416,13.0618,13.0618,0,0,1-17.0556,0Z"/>
      <path d="M580.35,88.1034a10.4859,10.4859,0,0,1-3.36-8.1279v-1.792a.5663.5663,0,0,1,.64-.6407h1.0884a.5668.5668,0,0,1,.64.6407v1.6a8.5459,8.5459,0,0,0,2.752,6.6562,10.5353,10.5353,0,0,0,7.36,2.4961,9.8719,9.8719,0,0,0,6.9761-2.3681,8.2161,8.2161,0,0,0,2.56-6.336,8.4,8.4,0,0,0-1.12-4.416,11.3812,11.3812,0,0,0-3.3281-3.3926,71.6714,71.6714,0,0,0-6.1763-3.7119,71.0479,71.0479,0,0,1-6.24-3.84,12.1711,12.1711,0,0,1-3.4238-3.68,10.2614,10.2614,0,0,1-1.28-5.3438,9.8579,9.8579,0,0,1,3.0718-7.7441,12.0122,12.0122,0,0,1,8.32-2.752q5.6954,0,8.96,3.1036a10.8251,10.8251,0,0,1,3.2642,8.2246v1.6a.5658.5658,0,0,1-.64.64h-1.1519a.5652.5652,0,0,1-.64-.64V56.8075a8.8647,8.8647,0,0,0-2.624-6.6885,9.9933,9.9933,0,0,0-7.232-2.5273,9.37,9.37,0,0,0-6.5278,2.1435,7.8224,7.8224,0,0,0-2.3682,6.1123,7.8006,7.8006,0,0,0,1.0244,4.16,10.387,10.387,0,0,0,3.0078,3.0391,62.8714,62.8714,0,0,0,5.9522,3.4882,71.0575,71.0575,0,0,1,6.72,4.2559,13.4674,13.4674,0,0,1,3.648,3.9365,10.049,10.049,0,0,1,1.28,5.1836,10.7177,10.7177,0,0,1-3.2637,8.1924q-3.2637,3.0717-8.832,3.0723Q583.71,91.1757,580.35,88.1034Z"/>
    </g>

    <g style="">
      <g>
        <path d="M99.835,36.0577l-39-22.5167a12,12,0,0,0-12,0l-39,22.5166a12.0339,12.0339,0,0,0-6,10.3924V91.4833a12.0333,12.0333,0,0,0,6,10.3923l39,22.5167a12,12,0,0,0,12,0l39-22.5167a12.0331,12.0331,0,0,0,6-10.3923V46.45A12.0334,12.0334,0,0,0,99.835,36.0577Zm-2,55.4256a4,4,0,0,1-2,3.4641l-39,22.5167a4.0006,4.0006,0,0,1-4,0l-39-22.5167a4,4,0,0,1-2-3.4641V46.45a4,4,0,0,1,2-3.4642l39-22.5166a4,4,0,0,1,4,0l39,22.5166a4,4,0,0,1,2,3.4642Z"/>
        <path d="M77.8567,82.0046h-2.866a4,4,0,0,0-1.9247.4934L55.7852,91.9833,35.835,80.4648V57.4872l19.95-11.5185,17.2893,9.4549a3.9993,3.9993,0,0,0,1.9192.4906h2.8632a2,2,0,0,0,2-2V51.2024a2,2,0,0,0-1.04-1.7547L59.628,38.9521a8.0391,8.0391,0,0,0-7.8428.09L31.8346,50.56a8.0246,8.0246,0,0,0-4,6.9287v22.976a8,8,0,0,0,4,6.9283l19.95,11.5186a8.0429,8.0429,0,0,0,7.8433.0879l19.19-10.5312a2,2,0,0,0,1.0378-1.7533v-2.71A2,2,0,0,0,77.8567,82.0046Z"/>
      </g>
      <g>
        <path d="M172.58,45.3618a15.0166,15.0166,0,0,0-15,14.9995V77.6387a15,15,0,0,0,30,0V60.3613A15.0166,15.0166,0,0,0,172.58,45.3618Zm7,32.2769a7,7,0,0,1-14,0V60.3613a7,7,0,0,1,14,0Z"/>
        <path d="M135.9138,53.4211a7.01,7.01,0,0,1,7.8681,6.0752.9894.9894,0,0,0,.9843.865h6.03a1.0108,1.0108,0,0,0,.9987-1.0971,15.0182,15.0182,0,0,0-15.7162-13.8837,15.2881,15.2881,0,0,0-14.2441,15.4163V77.2037A15.288,15.288,0,0,0,136.0792,92.62a15.0183,15.0183,0,0,0,15.7162-13.8842,1.0107,1.0107,0,0,0-.9987-1.0971h-6.03a.9894.9894,0,0,0-.9843.865,7.01,7.01,0,0,1-7.8679,6.0757,7.1642,7.1642,0,0,1-6.0789-7.1849V60.6057A7.1638,7.1638,0,0,1,135.9138,53.4211Z"/>
        <path d="M218.7572,72.9277a12.1585,12.1585,0,0,0,7.1843-11.0771V58.1494A12.1494,12.1494,0,0,0,213.7921,46H196.835a1,1,0,0,0-1,1V91a1,1,0,0,0,1,1h6a1,1,0,0,0,1-1V74h6.6216l7.9154,17.4138a1,1,0,0,0,.91.5862h6.5911a1,1,0,0,0,.91-1.4138Zm-.8157-11.0771A4.1538,4.1538,0,0,1,213.7926,66h-9.8511V54h9.8511a4.1538,4.1538,0,0,1,4.1489,4.1494Z"/>
        <path d="M260.835,46h-26a1,1,0,0,0-1,1V91a1,1,0,0,0,1,1h26a1,1,0,0,0,1-1V85a1,1,0,0,0-1-1h-19V72h13a1,1,0,0,0,1-1V65a1,1,0,0,0-1-1h-13V54h19a1,1,0,0,0,1-1V47A1,1,0,0,0,260.835,46Z"/>
        <path d="M298.835,46h-6a1,1,0,0,0-1,1V69.6475a7.0066,7.0066,0,1,1-14,0V47a1,1,0,0,0-1-1h-6a1,1,0,0,0-1,1V69.6475a15.0031,15.0031,0,1,0,30,0V47A1,1,0,0,0,298.835,46Z"/>
        <rect x="307.835" y="46" width="8" height="38" rx="1"/>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
`]
```

I downloaded this template from https://coreui.io/#c-compare.

Answer (score 3):

you can replace COREUI REACT logo with your own logo.

1. Make sure your logo in SVG format
2. Open your logo with your text editor - to see the code
3. Replace your logo code with that of COREUI REACT logo

Example - I removed COREUI REACT logo code only to keep

```
export const logoNegative = ['608 134', `

`]
```

Replaced with this to get a puppy instead:

```
export const logoNegative = ['608 134', `
  <svg id="Layer_3" enable-background="new 0 0 64 64" height="auto" viewBox="0 0 64 64" width="auto" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g><path d="m38 14h4.25c.205-2.463.445-5.333.445-5.333-1.028-3.839-4.531-6.667-8.695-6.667v8c0 2.209 1.791 4 4 4z" fill="#f4b2b0"/><path d="m37.5 16c-1.265 0-2.455.316-3.5.869-1.045-.553-2.235-.869-3.5-.869-4.142 0-7.5 3.358-7.5 7.5s3.358 7.5 7.5 7.5c1.265 0 2.455-.316 3.5-.869 1.045.553 2.235.869 3.5.869 4.142 0 7.5-3.358 7.5-7.5s-3.358-7.5-7.5-7.5z" fill="#f4b2b0"/><g fill="#b3404a"><path d="m37 7h2v4h-2z"/><path d="m29 7h2v4h-2z"/><path d="m26 20h2v2h-2z"/><path d="m28 24h2v2h-2z"/><path d="m40 20h2v2h-2z"/><path d="m38 24h2v2h-2z"/><path d="m16.162 27.914 2.733-5.466c.219-.439.088-.972-.31-1.258-.397-.288-.946-.244-1.292.104l-4.192 4.192c-2.645 2.643-4.101 6.159-4.101 9.899v.163c0 2.432.638 4.834 1.845 6.946l2.238 3.916c-.05.294-.083.591-.083.893v1.546c0 1.66.793 3.246 2.121 4.243l1.563 1.172c.198.148.316.383.316.631 0 .301-.167.571-.458.717-.951.475-1.542 1.43-1.542 2.493v.105c0 1.539 1.251 2.79 2.789 2.79h3.532c.543 1.177 1.727 2 3.106 2h5.744c2.112 0 3.829-1.717 3.829-3.829 0-1.022-.398-1.984-1.122-2.707-1.211-1.211-1.878-2.822-1.878-4.535v-.342c0-1.18-.222-2.335-.661-3.431-.987-2.467-2.439-4.67-4.318-6.548l-.314-.314-1.414 1.414.314.314c1.686 1.686 2.989 3.663 3.875 5.876.344.859.518 1.764.518 2.689v.342c0 2.248.875 4.361 2.464 5.95.346.345.536.804.536 1.292 0 1.009-.82 1.829-1.829 1.829h-5.744c-.787 0-1.427-.64-1.427-1.427 0-.22.052-.441.151-.638l.487-.975c.237-.475.362-1.004.362-1.533 0-1.792-.616-3.548-1.735-4.947-1.461-1.826-2.265-4.119-2.265-6.456v-1.526c0-3.794 1.44-7.361 4.044-10.101 1.244.616 2.578 1.054 3.976 1.287l1.067.178c.411 2.346 2.451 4.138 4.913 4.138s4.502-1.792 4.913-4.138l1.067-.178c1.398-.233 2.732-.672 3.976-1.287 2.604 2.739 4.044 6.306 4.044 10.101v1.526c0 2.337-.804 4.63-2.265 6.456-1.119 1.399-1.735 3.156-1.735 4.947 0 .528.125 1.058.362 1.533l.487.974c.099.198.151.419.151.639 0 .787-.64 1.427-1.427 1.427h-5.744c-1.009 0-1.829-.82-1.829-1.829 0-.488.19-.947.536-1.293 1.589-1.588 2.464-3.702 2.464-5.949v-.342c0-.925.174-1.83.518-2.689.885-2.213 2.188-4.19 3.875-5.876l.314-.314-1.414-1.414-.314.314c-1.878 1.878-3.331 4.082-4.318 6.548-.439 1.096-.661 2.251-.661 3.431v.342c0 1.713-.667 3.324-1.878 4.536-.724.723-1.122 1.684-1.122 2.706 0 2.112 1.717 3.829 3.829 3.829h5.744c1.379 0 2.563-.823 3.106-2h3.532c1.538 0 2.789-1.251 2.789-2.789v-.105c0-1.063-.591-2.019-1.564-2.505-.269-.135-.436-.406-.436-.706 0-.247.118-.483.315-.631l1.563-1.173c1.329-.997 2.122-2.583 2.122-4.242v-1.546c0-1.05-.308-2.067-.891-2.941-.943-1.414-2.494-2.274-4.182-2.347-.316-3.602-1.786-6.956-4.216-9.655.707-.488 1.377-1.034 1.995-1.652.391-.391.391-1.023 0-1.414l-2.412-2.412c.452-1.038.706-2.181.706-3.382 0-2.475-1.096-4.754-2.872-6.337l4.831-6.442c.671-.894 1.041-2.003 1.041-3.122 0-1.984-1.103-3.768-2.877-4.655l-3.676-1.838c-.321-.16-.704-.137-1.002.062l-2.089 1.393c-1.564-.993-3.408-1.561-5.356-1.561s-3.792.568-5.356 1.561l-2.089-1.393c-.299-.2-.682-.223-1.002-.062l-3.676 1.838c-1.774.887-2.877 2.671-2.877 4.655 0 1.119.37 2.228 1.041 3.123l4.831 6.442c-1.776 1.582-2.872 3.861-2.872 6.336 0 1.201.254 2.344.705 3.381l-2.412 2.412c-.391.391-.391 1.023 0 1.414.618.618 1.288 1.164 1.995 1.652-2.158 2.397-3.55 5.311-4.056 8.458l-.01-.01c-2.078-2.077-3.222-4.839-3.222-7.778v-.196c0-1.7.401-3.4 1.162-4.919zm36.283 17.557c.363.544.555 1.178.555 1.832v1.546c0 1.034-.494 2.021-1.321 2.642l-1.563 1.173c-.699.524-1.116 1.357-1.116 2.231 0 1.063.591 2.019 1.564 2.505.269.134.436.405.436.705v.105c0 .436-.354.79-.789.79h-3.278c-.057-.332-.144-.658-.295-.96l-.487-.974c-.099-.198-.151-.419-.151-.639 0-1.339.46-2.652 1.297-3.698 1.743-2.179 2.703-4.915 2.703-7.705v-.986c.987.091 1.889.598 2.445 1.433zm-18.445-8.471c-1.654 0-3-1.346-3-3v-2.027c.679-.041 1.351-.158 2-.358v3.385h2v-3.385c.649.2 1.321.318 2 .358v2.027c0 1.654-1.346 3-3 3zm-1-13.983c.189-.023.502-.021.728-.019l.272.002.272-.001c.225-.002.54-.004.728.019-.009.819-.682 1.939-.997 1.983-.321-.044-.994-1.165-1.003-1.984zm12.557 6.955c-1.683 1.432-3.706 2.373-5.907 2.739l-.65.108v-.96c2.127-.381 3.977-1.553 5.242-3.203zm-10.557-26.902c3.139.396 5.791 2.622 6.682 5.706l-.352 4.224h-3.33c-1.654 0-3-1.346-3-3zm9 1.048 1.229.614c1.092.547 1.771 1.645 1.771 2.867 0 .689-.228 1.372-.641 1.922l-3.075 4.1.716-8.621zm-2-.916.003 1.715-.007.089c-.304-.405-.638-.784-.997-1.136zm-16 0 1.001.668c-.361.354-.695.734-1 1.14l-.001-.01zm-4.359 6.319c-.413-.551-.641-1.233-.641-1.922 0-1.222.679-2.32 1.771-2.866l1.23-.615.001.966.711 8.537zm6.692 7.849-.667-1.886c-.265.094-.51.221-.761.339l-.589-7.042c.89-3.087 3.544-5.316 6.684-5.711v6.93c0 2.757 2.243 5 5 5h3.163l-.068.822c-.251-.118-.496-.245-.761-.338l-.667 1.886c2.592.916 4.333 3.38 4.333 6.13 0 3.584-2.916 6.5-6.5 6.5-.871 0-1.708-.178-2.5-.511v-2.774c1.228-.669 2-2.442 2-3.715 0-.596-.179-1.076-.531-1.425-.593-.588-1.417-.582-2.212-.576l-.257.001-.256-.001c-.796-.009-1.62-.013-2.212.576-.353.349-.532.829-.532 1.425 0 1.273.772 3.046 2 3.715v2.774c-.792.333-1.629.511-2.5.511-3.584 0-6.5-2.916-6.5-6.5 0-2.75 1.741-5.214 4.333-6.13zm-4.575 11.286c1.265 1.65 3.115 2.822 5.242 3.203v.96l-.65-.108c-2.201-.367-4.224-1.308-5.907-2.739zm-3.055 24.074c.837 1.045 1.297 2.358 1.297 3.697 0 .22-.052.441-.151.638l-.487.975c-.151.301-.238.628-.295.959h-3.278c-.435.001-.789-.353-.789-.788v-.105c0-.301.167-.571.458-.717.951-.476 1.542-1.431 1.542-2.494 0-.873-.417-1.707-1.115-2.231l-1.563-1.172c-.828-.622-1.322-1.61-1.322-2.643v-1.546c0-.654.192-1.288.555-1.832.556-.835 1.458-1.341 2.445-1.433v.986c0 2.79.96 5.526 2.703 7.706zm-3.895-10.508.001.001c-1.083.318-2.04.975-2.733 1.895l-1.495-2.616c-1.034-1.811-1.581-3.869-1.581-5.954v-.163c0-3.125 1.187-6.068 3.347-8.314-.881 1.782-1.347 3.773-1.347 5.762v.196c0 3.473 1.352 6.738 3.808 9.193z"/></g></g></svg>
`]
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

The solution of @sam1973 is valid, but you can also directly replace the content of `TheSidebar.js` CSidebarBrand component